# Update BLOB field image file with PHP (Oracle database)

Tags: php, oracle, image, blob

hope everyone is doing great.

I'm trying to update a BLOB file in my Oracle database with an image file, but it's not working for some reason or another..

This is my code as of now:

```
        $signatureImage = file_get_contents('signatures/' . $id . '_SIGNATURE.png');
        $lob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
        $signatureSql = oci_parse($conn, "UPDATE DT_WEB SET DT_SIGNATURE = EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE DT_ID = '$id' RETURNING DT_SIGNATURE INTO :SIGNATUREIMG");
        oci_bind_by_name($signatureSql, ':SIGNATUREIMG', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
        oci_execute($signatureSql, OCI_DEFAULT);
        $lob->saveFile($signatureImage);
        $lob->free();
        oci_free_statement($signatureSql);
```

I'm honestly not sure of the issue as I don't usually work with Oracle databases.

I appreciate any help and tips, thanks everyone.

Comment: So I changed `$lob->saveFile` to `$lob->save` and now it's updating the database, but I'm getting a black image in the database. What could be the issue?